# self paying contract

Tags: transactions, contract-design

I would like to create a contract that can be used without ether.

Is it possible to create a function in a contract that pays for its own gas?

I am aware that this leaves the door open to abuse and that a troll will probably call the function until there is no ETH left.

But for the sake of argument: is it technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this isn't possible. The nearest to this you can get is a contract that refunds the cost of the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, today, but I have seen indications that it's contemplated for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Should be part of the Metropolis release according to [this post of Vitalik](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/12/04/ethereum-research-update/) (last sentence)

> EIP 86 (account security abstraction) – move the logic for verifying
>   signatures and nonces into contracts, allowing developers to
>   experiment with new signature schemes, privacy-preserving technologies
>   and modifications to parts of the protocol without requiring further
>   hard forks or support at the protocol level.  Also allows contracts to pay for gas.

Answer (score 1):

What you asked is going to be the part of the SERENITY. Currently, Ethereum is HOMESTEAD, then there shall be METROPOLIS, & later SERENITY. so at least a year, you should consider.

Please check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQtRzhgHEBg

In this video, Hudson is talking about self-paying contracts @10:18, exactly your requirement as I see.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR it's not possible. The one who calls contract method (unless it's `constant`) pays price of the gas that was used during the transaction.